# Lock Star Rating System After User Votes - RateIt jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, django, rating-system

I have the [RateIt jQuery Plugin](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm) working on a Django application. I'm using Ajax to capture the values and send them to the server and update the values on the page.

Currently, each time the user clicks the stars, I calculate the average and total number of clicks and display those next to the stars. Since this project is in development, I've been more interested in getting it working and displaying lots of data.

But from a usability point of view, I think allowing the user to set the rating once, twice or, in my case, 5 times seems like a better way to go. I am using something from the docs that almost does what I want:

```
$(ri).rateit('readonly', !$(ri).rateit('readonly'));
```

I bump a counter in the script (eg, `counter++;`) and inside an `if` statement, I set to `readonly`. The problem is if the user clicks the stars again, it toggles `write` mode (non-`readonly`).

Each click after this simply toggles `readonly` mode.

**UPDATE**

With the help from @Gidon (creator of RateIt, I believe), I have solved this issue. Here is the bit in the Ajax script. I started a counter outside the Ajax call with `counter = 0;` and then iterated it with `counter++;` and used this to test:

```
if (counter >= 3) {
    $(ri).rateit('readonly', true);
    $('.rateit').off('click');
}
```

I put it into `readonly` mode and removed the click binding with jQuery's `off()`.

Thanks for the help @Gidon. This works OK. The user can refresh the page and get more votes, but I have some ideas about using sessions to prevent this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toggle happens because of this part: `!$(ri).rateit('readonly')`.
This is build from two parts `!`  and `$(ri).rateit('readonly')`. The exclamation mark (`!`) is the logical not operator, and negates whatever comes after it, (`$(ri).rateit('readonly')`.

So it says, take the current value of the readonly property, and flip it, thus 
creating the toggle effect.

What you want to do is:

`$(ri).rateit('readonly', true);`

Which forces it into readonly mode.

Comment: Geez, now I feel like a dummy ;-) Thanks for reaching out, BTW. I really appreciate it. I swear I tried that and other approaches, like `$('.rateit').attr('data-rateit-readonly', 'true');` to no avail. Maybe I tried something similar... Anyway, thanks again. great plugin!

Comment: Oh yeah, one more quick question. I implemented your recommendation and it worked. But I still have a lingering issue such that the stars (while in `readonly` mode) are still taking clicks. They are radio buttons in disguise, right? Should I be disabling them too? I'm biding the Ajax to a click event (to send data to server), so maybe that is my problem.

Comment: It could use radio buttons, or a range element, or a select element. But the basic usage (which looks for a div/span with the rateit class) doesn;t use anything in disguise. Looking qat your answer update, you're are adding your own event listener to the rate it component, you could however use the build in events , which take care of the read only case. `$('.rateit').on('rated', ....)`

Comment: So I could do something like: `$('.rateit').on('rated', function() { $(ri).rateit('readonly', true); });` ?

Comment: Yes, that would mean that after rating it is put into read only mode. Much like one of the examples on my sample page (see http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm#ex_11)

Comment: Damn, I missed that... I actually used your snippet for the Ajax method but must have deleted that line inadvertently (and/or ignorantly). My apologies for not realizing... Thanks again. great plugin!

Comment: Sorry to keep hitting you up, but I had another question. I am trying to "unhook" the stars from additional clicks calling the Ajax script by putting them into `readonly` mode. While this is successful, if I don't use `$('.rateit').off('click');` then the user can click the stars in `readonly` mode and the values still get sent to the server. With the `off()` function, the stars aren't clickable (no data sent) but I see this weird delay before that happens, such that if the user hovers the stars to the left, the value gets stuck after a split second.

Comment: Thanks for this! It just helped me solve my problem as well.